# Vector<Custom> Access Violation

Tags: c++, vector, access-violation

I recently submitted a final project that ended up working, but not the way I was hoping. Basically, I created a custom class `Book` that I then loaded into a `vector<Book>`. Book has a function `deserialize()` that I could call like:

```
Book tempBook;
tempBook.setSerialized(stringBook);
tempBook.deserialize();
```

But I if I tried to call:

```
std::vector<Book> book_vec;
Book tempBook;
tempBook.setSerialized(stringBook);
book_vec.push_back(tempBook);
book_vec.front().deserialize();
```

I get an access violation error (assume `book_vec` has only 1 item)

`setSerialized` puts a flat string representation of the book into `tempBook`

`deserialize` tokenizes that flat string, and loads the tokens into `vectors` of `strings`

Why can't I call `deserialize` from `book_vec`???????

Comment: I suspect front is returning a const Book object.

Comment: What would cause that? The vector, nor the book, are `const`

Comment: Provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) and I'm sure someone will be able to figure it out.

Comment: I just realized that `front()` returns a reference... so the object itself is probably sitting in a private array inside the vector... could that be it?

Comment: I'll have to work on the `short` part of SSCCE before I can post

Comment: The value return by front can be a const ref. But I can't reproduce it.